# Hashing the content of a certificate

Tags: macos, encryption

How can I hash the entire encoded content of a certificate including the signature in coreFoundation?

I am actually looking for an equivalent to Windows CryptHashCertificate().

Sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the answer in case anyone finds this useful...

I managed to match the result of the Windows function by searching the certificate inside the keychain and then casting the search item to SecCertificateRef :

```
// certItem is of SecKeychainItemRef 


CSSM_DATA certData;
unsigned char checksumResult[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
SecCertificateRef certRef = (SecCertificateRef) certItem;

SecCertificateGetData(certRef, &certData);
memset(checksumResult, 0, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH);
CC_MD5(certData.Data, certData.Length, checksumResult);
```

Comment: Except that `SecCertificateGetData()` was deprecated in 10.7.  Do you know the official way to do this?